# return one table from two tables where condition exists in one or the other

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a little weird, but I need to select from one of two tables that have a given unique identifier. Let's say that table A looks like:

```
ID CallNumber Caller
```

and table B looks like:

```
ID CallNumber Caller
```

and I have a unique identifier that could be in either one. How could I write a select statement that would return these columns and display the data from either table A or table B? What I have come up with so far is:

```
SELECT 
coalesce(a.ID,t.id) as ID
,coalesce(a.CallNumber,t.CallNumber) as CallNumber
,coalesce(a.Caller,t.Caller) as Caller
FROM tableA a
right join  tableB b on b.ID = a.ID
where a.ID = '' or b.ID = ''
```

but this will only return the unique identifier if the ID lives in table A.

Comment: Sample data and expected result will us to understand better

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I guess `t.ID`, `t.caller` etc are supposed to be `b.ID`, `b.caller`...?

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be one query then you could query both tables and mash up the results. You don't need to bother with joining tables or other logic.

```
select
    ID,
    CallNumber,
    Caller
from
    tableA
where
    ID = theID

union all -- adding 'all' avoids unnecessary sorting operation

select
    ID,
    CallNumber,
    Caller
from
    tableB
where
    ID = theID
```